# How do I split a file by a grep with ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, grep

I have a file that contains many bits of code, and I'd like to refactor all of them into their own files.  The file in question has some 30k lines, so I don't want to do it by hand.

Each of the sections starts:

```
module MyModule
```

(I've changed that name)

---

Is there a function to split the file per-mark?  When I use `File.readlines` I can't find a nice way to split the array.

I don't care how you'd think to name them.

Comment: What do you mean split the file? Into separate new files?

Comment: @squiguy Yes, into files

Comment: I strongly suggest doing it by hand and running specs each time you move something around so you know you didn't break anything at each step.  It will take longer but will be solid refactor.  I definitely would not try to automate that - and I love automating things.

Comment: @kikuchiyo it would be great to live in a world where specs exists already.

Comment: Wow, no specs.  I used to work at a place like that when I first got out of college.  Back then we used to manually test and make iterative changes.  You should be able to do this if you know what the code is supposed to do.  If you don't know what it is supposed to do, definitely do not refactor the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has a great method that is part of Enumerable called [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before):

```
require 'pp'

modules = DATA.readlines.map(&:chomp).slice_before(/^module MyModule/).map{ |a| a.join("\n") }
pp modules

__END__
module MyModule
  # 1 stuff
end

module MyModule
  # 2 stuff
end

module MyModule
  # 3 stuff
end
```

This is the output showing what `modules` contains:

```
["module MyModule\n  # 1 stuff\nend\n",
 "module MyModule\n  # 2 stuff\nend\n",
 "module MyModule\n  # 3 stuff\nend"]
```

`DATA` is Ruby sleight-of-hand inherited from Perl. Everything in the source file after `__END__` is considered part of a "data" block, which is made available to the running code by the interpreter in the `DATA` file handle, and acts like a data file. That means we can use IO methods on it, such as `readlines`, similarly to how we'd use `IO.readlines`. I'm using `__END__` and `DATA` here because they're convenient for simple tests and short scripts.

`readlines` doesn't remove the trailing line-end when it reads the line, which is what `map(&:chomp)` does. `DATA.read.split("\n")` would have accomplished the same thing.

`slice_before` is the magic that makes this work. It takes an array and iterates through it, creating sub-arrays that start each time the pattern finds a hit. Following that it's just a case of rejoining the contents of the sub-arrays back into a single string, prior to writing to the files.

After that you just have to loop over `modules`, saving each one to a different file:

```
modules.each.with_index(1) do |m, i|
  File.write("module_#{ i }.rb", m)
end
```

[`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) is a nice little method in Enumerator, that is useful when we need to know which item in an array we're processing. It's similar to `each_with_index` except we can specify the starting offset value, `1` in this case.

Comment: I gave you the answer because `slice_before` was the method I needed most.  You also provided some interesting errata and trivia that educated me.  The question itself is only complexified by this use of `__DATA__`, but I'll certainly remember that.  If you have an in-the-wild use case, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: `DATA` is a convenience when storing content resembling a file on disk or available on line rather than waste time showing how to create a sample-data file and reference it. Use case for `DATA`? Ruby doesn't use it that much but it's used for lots of Perl code.

Comment: This link is useful to explain.  Ruby doesn't have `__DATA__` but the rest is valid. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_07.htm

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your code.

```
File.read('lib/odin.rb').split(/module Odin/).each do |mod|
    File.open("#{mod[/class (\w+)/, 1]}.rb", "w") do |f| 
        f.write("module Odin")
        f.write(mod)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer, in writing out the question in detail.

I'm posting it as an answer, but I'll award the answer to someone else that has a better solution:

```
big_file = File.readlines 'lib/odin.rb'
big_file.
  join(' ').
  split(/module Odin/). 
  map!{|w| w.prepend("module Odin\n") }.
  each do |f| 
    name = "#{f.match(/class ([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].underscore}.rb"
    File.open(name, "w") do |n| 
      n.write(f)
    end
  end
```

I also thought of a nice way to name the output files based on content; but I don't care how you'd think to name them.